# Exporting a Neo4j database to CytoScape

Tags: neo4j, cytoscape

I am trying to export a neo4j database from Neo4j to cytoscape.

I have tried with using a rest web service but it is not a good idea as the database is big and my backend crashed.

Is there a better way to do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the various Cytoscape Neo4J apps doesn't work for you, I would suggest exporting the network of interest as a CSV and then using Cytoscape's import capability to pull it in.  See: https://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/ for some pointers on how to do that.

-- scooter